# mongodump not recognizing --uri

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am not sure if I don't have the latest mongo or mongodump but I get `cannot recognize "uri"` when I run the following in the terminal on my MAC.

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://blah:mypword@blahprod.lq1eee.mongodb.net/mydb
```

I also tried these first:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew 
brew install mongodb-database-tools
brew install mongodb-community@4.4
```

When I look in MongoDB Atlas it says in order to mongodump then use the Example above. Is there something else I need to install?

If I try this

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://blah:mypword@blahprod.lq1eee.mongodb.net/mydb
```

I get `positional arguments not allowed:`

**The ultimate goal is to just download the collections as we are deleting the db and moving off mongodb.  Ideally, I would like to also download the DB as JSON or some other file for use later when we rebuild with Firebase or a cheaper MongoDB alternative.**

Comment: Try `mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://blah:mypword@blahprod.lq1eee.mongodb.net/mydb"`

Comment: Same result -> error parsing command line options: unknown option "uri"

Comment: Which version do you have?

Comment: Version of what and how to find out?

Comment: `mongodump --version` and maybe once you should try `mongodump --help`

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit And I have. --help is about 70 worthless